# How can I split these two object strings so I can put into database

Tags: java, android, string, object, split

```
while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
     String phone = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
     String pon = name ;
     System.out.println("phone" + phone + name);
     listItems.add(pon + phone) ;
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I am getting the phone number and name from a persons contacts. i have to stringify each object to pass it along to my list view (multiple check). now i select multiple choices i want to again separate the two (the contact name and the phone number associated with it) so i can put them into separate columns in my database. how can i split the two once it is a string in an array adapter?

Comment: You can use String.split(). but its depends upon how they are concatenated in your input string. Can you show us example of that.

Comment: Do not mix model and view.  The display on the list view is "view".  It is a visual representation of the model.  Store the name and phone number in model as two strings then use the model representation when storing it to the database.

Comment: listItems.add(pon + phone) ;

Comment: @Dnaso Is it like `Name 1234567890` or `Name1234567890` or anything like that example.

Comment: @DwB that is exactly what I want to do. How can I pass the strings separately in my while loop to my array adapter? I want to make it a dual line adapter anyway, and if i can pass both separately as (separate items), i want to.

Comment: make a class that has two strings (name and phone).  I will name this class HootBerry.  Create and populate a List<HootBerry>.  Store the List<HootBerry> in the listView extra data area.  Iterate through the list to create the elements that display in the listView

Comment: @SMIT there is a space in between, but i didnt want to split on spaces because people might have last names and then split on white space won't work

Answer (score 0):

> how can i split these two object strings so i can put into database

Well. Probably in your ListView you have your data formatted as(also you can ensure specific format for easier work in a future).

```
John 23459395
```

Now when you select items from your `ListView`, you can access to them and save them into temporary List. Then each item in List you can split with **split()** method.

```
List<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
// selection from ListView
String[] temp;
for (String s: selectedItems) {
   temp = s.split(" "); // or other regex based on format of source
   // insert into db
}
```

But this depends on format of source.

### Update:

Your actual approach you can improve. Look, now you are fetching name and phoneNumber from `Cursor`

I recommend you to create own class for instance called `User` that will have properties name, phonenumber, etc. Then you create `ArrayList<User>()` and set it as datasource to your ListAdapter.

I don't now if you are using own implemented subclass of Adapter or not. If not, you need to override `toString()` method in your User class to get proper string representation of User.

Comment: I also dont want to "force formatting" on people, B will that split work if there is a last name IE  JOHN DOE 494959?

Comment: @Dnaso for this reason i recommend you to use approach at the end of my asnwer, check it out.

Comment: yes, I was trying to say( i am a web programmer) I am shaky on all this android (if this was web it would be easy as pie) but making class isn't optimal because I am kind of lost , although I guess I am treating this like a web-based program and that is where i am having issues.

Comment: @Dnaso so write me what is confusing for you.

Comment: but a shot in the dark.. i can do .. public ArrayList<User>(int number String name){  then create object and return list?

Comment: I am should i just create a class for getting the phone number and just return the array list object back to my activity's array adapter?

Comment: @Dnaso no how i mentioned, create class User that will have private fields: string name, string phonenumber a create ArrayList<User>

Answer (score 0):

Use a string inbbetween name and phone and use that string to split it again.

**Code Sample**

```
while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
     String phone = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
     String pon = name ;
     System.out.println("phone" + phone + name);
/* Following code changed here...Hoping that "!@#$" doesnt exists in pon or phone data. Or you can replace it with some other string which will not come in these objects. */
     listItems.add(pon +"!@#$"+ phone) ;
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

How to retrive and split: Sample method

```
ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        listItems.add("Joseph!@#$325625123");
        listItems.add("John!@#$5214252142");
        for (String strData : listItems)
        {
            int index = strData.indexOf("!@#$");
            if (index > -1)
            {
                String name = strData.substring(0, index);
                String phone = strData.substring(index + 4);// 4 is the length of the substitute string
                System.out.println(name + ", " + phone);
                // Code to insert name and phone database
            }

        }
```

Result of above method will be as below

Joseph, 325625123

John, 5214252142